# Entity Framework ASP.NET CRUD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a student page and it does student insert, delete, update. I have another page that course does course insert, delete, update.Now I want to student assign to courses. Am I clear? Should it see in another page?Can you help me?

Comment: you do not need to specify the junction table, and for natural join you'll mostly have to configure your FK relationships. for creating the many-to-many-relationship, you should see the EF tutorial.

Comment: @ DevilSuichiro I just couldnt decide what should I do. I am trying to student assign to courses. Therefore in web site assigning process can do in student page or courses page or needed new page?

Comment: @ DevilSuichiro I have a student page and it does student insert, delete, update. I have another page that course does course insert, delete, update.Now I want to student assign to courses. Am I clear? Should it see in another page?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hyperlink on the student page called "Assign Courses" or something similar:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvStudents" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField 
            DataNavigateUrlFields="Name,Surname,ID"
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="AssignCourses.aspx?Name={0}&Surname={1}&ID={2}"
            Text="AssignCourses" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Clicking on this hyperlink will take the user to a new page called *AssignCourses.aspx* and pass through the name,surname and ID(or any other field you like) in the query string.

On the *AssignCourses.aspx* write code to display a list of courses already assigned to the student.Also, have a drop down listing all the other courses.If the user clicks on *Assign Course* button use the course id and the student id (from the query string) to assign the student to the course.

**Reading values from query string on the *AssignCourses.aspx* page:**

```
string name = Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString();
string surname = Request.QueryString["Surname"].ToString();
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

lblInfo.Text = String.Format("Assign courses for - {0} {1}", name, surname);
```

**EDIT:**

If you're using ASP.NET MVC you can add a hyperlink to the AssignCourses view using Razor syntax, something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click here to assign course", "AssignCoursesAction", "PutControllerNameHere", new { id=student.ID }, null)
```

Comment: Thank you but asp.net mvc how can write it?